# Update failed. First exception on row 0; first error: MISSING_ARGUMENT, Id not specified in an update call: [] unitTest3: line 73, column 1

Tags: unit-test, community

```
@isTest
private class TestcountRecord{
    static testMethod void unitTest(){
        Test.StartTest();

        Account Acc = new Account();
        Acc.Name = 'test';
        insert acc;

        Contact con = new Contact();
        con.lastname = 'Test';
        con.AccountId = Acc.id;
        insert con;

        Account acc2=[select id,name,My_Contact__c from account where id=:Acc.id];
        //acc2.My_Contact__c=
        System.assertEquals(acc2.name, 'test');

        con.lastname = 'Test1';
        update con;

        Test.StopTest();
    }

    static testMethod void unitTest2(){
        Test.StartTest();
        Account Acc2 = new Account();
        Acc2.Name = 'Acc2';
        insert Acc2;

        Account Acc3 = new Account();
        Acc3.Name = 'Acc3';
        insert acc3;

        Account Acc4 = new Account();
        Acc4.Name = 'Acc4';
        insert Acc4;

        Contact con2 = new Contact();
        con2.lastname = 'Test';
        con2.AccountId = Acc2.id;
        insert con2;

        Contact con3 = new Contact();
        con3.lastname = 'Test3';
        con3.AccountId = Acc3.id;
        insert con3;

        con2.AccountID=Acc4.id;
        update con2;
        Test.StopTest();   
    }    

    static testMethod void unitTest3(){
        Account acc=new Account();
        acc.name='account';
        insert acc;

        contact con=new contact();
        con.lastname='Test';
        con.AccountId=acc.id;
        insert con;

        Account acc2=new Account();
        acc2.name='test';
        acc2.id=null;
        insert acc2;

        contact con2=new contact();
        con.lastname='Test';
        con2.AccountId=acc2.id;
        update con2;  
    }
}
```

Comment: is your issue resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `unitTest3` method //first insert then perform update

Like your exception says.

> MISSING_ARGUMENT, Id not specified in an update call:

Means you are performing update operation on newly records(which don't have Id.)

So you need to first insert your newly created record.

It will generate the Id for your record. after that Perform Update DML.

```
 contact con2=new contact();
 con.lastname='Test';
 insert con2;            //first insert then perform update
 con2.AccountId=acc2.id;
 update con2;
```

Comment: Correct enough, but I think this answer could be expanded a bit to explain *why*. I almost gave a -1 until I realized you were indeed correct.